# Update "posting" in PHP, but when checking database, the database shows NULL

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

I am working on this code, and I am at wits end right now. For some reason my I can't update my database.

The code below is updated, the code no longer works, the update command seems to stall the PHP and causes and error. If anyone can resolve this it would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <?php
require_once('connectvars.php');
echo '<div id="postwrap">'
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>PDI NCMR - Edit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/postie.css" />
</head>
<body>
   <div id="logo">
    <img src="../images/PDI_Logo_2.1.gif" alt="PDI Logo" />
</div>

<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// Connect to the database
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Enter data into the database
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['id']));
    $ab = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ab']));
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime ($_POST['date']))));
    $part = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['part']));
    $rev = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['rev']));
    $partdesc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['partdesc']));
    $ncmrqty = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ncmrqty']));
    $comp = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['comp']));
    $ncmrid = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ncmrid']));
    $rma = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['rma']));
    $jno = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['jno']));
    $fdt = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fdt']));
    $cof = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['cof']));
    $fab1= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fab1']));
    $fab2= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fab2']));
    $fab3= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['fab3']));
    $non= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['non']));
    $dis= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['dis']));
    $comm= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['comm']));
    $caad= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['caad']));
    $po= mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['po']));
    $pod = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['pod']))));
    $dri = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim(date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['dri']))));

    $query = "UPDATE ncmr SET ab = '$ab', date = '$date', part = '$part', rev = '$rev' , partdesc = '$partdesc' , ncmrqty = '$ncmrqty' , comp = '$comp' , ncmrid = '$ncmrid' , rma = '$rma' , jno = '$jno' , fdt = '$fdt' , cof = '$cof' , fab1 = '$fab1' , fab2 = '$fab2' , fab3 = '$fab3' , non = '$non' , dis = '$dis' , comm = '$comm' , caad = '$caad' , po = '$po' , pod = '$pod' , dri = '$dri'  WHERE id = "$_GET['id']"";

// echo your raw query and look for obvious errors
     echo "Query is : " . $query . "<br />";

// and at least use a basic mechanism to trap possibles errors
       mysqli_query($dbc, $query)  or die('Query Error : ' . mysqli_error($dbc));


// Confirm success with the user
        echo '<p>If you wish to edit more NCMRs, please <a href="list.php">go to the admin page!</a></p>';

        // echo your raw query and look for obvious errors
     echo "Query is : " . $query . "<br />";
// Clear the form data
    $id = "";
    $ab = "";
    $date = "";
    $part = "";
    $rev = "";
    $partdesc = "";
    $ncmrqty = "";
    $comp = "";
    $ncmrid = "";
    $rma = "";
    $jno = "";
    $fdt = "";
    $cof = "";
    $fab1= "";
    $fab2= "";
    $fab3= "";
    $non= "";
    $dis= "";
    $comm= "";
    $caad= "";
    $po= "";
    $pod = "";
    $dri = "";
            mysqli_close($dbc);
            }

  else {    

// Connect to the database
  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
// Grab the profile data from the database
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ncmr WHERE id = '$id'";
  }
  else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM ncmr WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'";
  }

  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) { 
// The user row was found so display the user data
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
    echo '<form action="edit.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>" method="POST">'
    echo '<fieldset>';

        echo '<div id="box1">';
            if (empty($row['ab'])) $row['ab'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['date'])) $row['date'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['part'])) $row['part'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['rev'])) $row['rev'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['partdesc'])) $row['partdesc'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['ncmrqty'])) $row['ncmrqty'] = "Empty";
            echo '<div id="ab"><span class="b">Added By:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ab" value="' . $row['ab'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="date"><span class="b">Date Filed:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="date" value="' . $row['date'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="part"><span class="b">Part Number:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="part" value="' . $row['part'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="rev"><span class="b">Part Revision:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="rev" value="' . $row['rev'] . '" /></div>';
            echo '<div id="partdesc"><span class="b">Part Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="22">' . $row['partdesc'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="ncmrqty"><span class="b">NCMR Qty:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ncmrqty" value="' . $row['ncmrqty'] . '" /></div>';
        echo '</div>';

//Company, Customer NCMR, Internal RMA, and Job Number
        echo '<div id="box2">';
            if (empty($row['comp'])) $row['comp'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['ncmrid'])) $row['ncmrid'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['rma'])) $row['rma'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['jno'])) $row['jno'] = "Empty";
                echo '<div id="comp"><span class="b">Company:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="comp" value="' . $row['comp'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="ncmrid"><span class="b">Customer NCMR ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="ncmrid" value="' . $row['ncmrid'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="rma"><span class="b">Internal RMA #:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="rma" value="' . $row['rma'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="jno"><span class="b">Job #:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="jno" value="' . $row['jno'] . '" /></div>';
        echo '</div>';

//Type of Failure and Class of Failure
        echo '<div id="box3">';
            echo '<h2>Failure</h2>';
                echo '<div id="cof"><span class="b">Class of Failure:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="cof"  size="15" value="' . $row['cof'] . '" /></div>';
                echo '<div id="fdt"><span class="b">Failure Due To:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="fdt"  size="15" value="' . $row['fdt'] . '" /></div>';

            echo '</div>';

//Fabricators
        echo '<div id="box4">';
            echo '<h2>Fabricators</h2>';
if ($row['fab1']="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab1">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab1'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo'<div id="fab1">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab1'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}


if ($row['fab2']="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab2">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab2'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo '<div id="fab2"><span class="b"></span><input type="text" name="fab1"  size="20" value="' . $row['fab1'] . '" /></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
if ($row['fab3']="--None--")
{
    echo'<div id="fab3">';
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    $mysqli->select_db('user');
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM user"); 
    echo "<SELECT name='fab3'>\n";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='{$row['user']}'>{$row['user']}</option>\n";
    }
    echo "</select>\n";
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo '<div id="fab3"><span class="b"></span><input type="text" name="fab1"  size="20" value="' . $row['fab1'] . '" /></div>';
    echo '</div>';
}       echo '</div>';

//Nonconformity, Disposition, Comments and Comments & Additional Details
        echo '<div id="box5">';
            if (empty($row['non'])) $row['non'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['dis'])) $row['dis'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['comm'])) $row['comm'] = "Empty";
            if (empty($row['caad'])) $row['caad'] = "Empty";

            echo '<div id="non"><span class="b">Nonconformity:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['non'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="dis"><span class="b">Disposition:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['dis'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="comm"><span class="b">Comments:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['comm'] . '</textarea></div>';
            echo '<div id="caad"><span class="b">Comments and/or Additional Details:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><textarea rows="4" cols="105">' . $row['caad'] . '</textarea></div>';

                echo '<div id="podr">';
                        if (empty($row['po'])) $row['po'] ="Empty";
                        if (empty($row['pod'])) $row['pod'] ="Empty";
                        if (empty($row['dir'])) $row['dri'] ="Empty";

                    echo '<div id="po"><span class="b">PO:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="po"  size="7" value="' . $row['po'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="pod"><span class="b">PO Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="pod"  size="7" value="' . $row['pod'] . '" /></div>';
                    echo '<div id="dri"><span class="b">Date Received:&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><input type="text" name="dri"  size="7" value="' . $row['dri'] . '" /></div>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '<div id="button2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Edits" name="submit" /></div>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</fieldset>';
echo '</form>';
        }
    }

echo '</div>';

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have an sql injection here $query = "SELECT * FROM ncmr WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'"; and for the line above I don't see where's declared $id.

Comment: have you tried using echo mysql_error(); right after the insert query?

Comment: not to mention the xss in the form.....

Comment: Your form method is POST so you need to add hidden field and preseve the ID so on submit you may get correct ID value using $_POST['id'].

Comment: Ya, you should have another query getting the id's from the database, return it as an array, check to see if the value is in the array before you run it.  Or write regex to match number, aka "\d"

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa The id, is coming from another page, it pushes the from said page and then allows the rest to be populated.

Comment: @MattRidge - Do you want to insert or update (from your post and this message - Your comments have been successfully entered.).

Comment: @AVD, I want to technically insert, but I was told the only way to enter data into an existing stream of data was to update, so I used update.  If there is a better way please advise me I am still learning.

Comment: Of course you have to insert a row and use insert statement instead of update.

Comment: @AVD, I already have the rows set up "ncmrsr" and "ncmrsc", how to I insert the code into a pre-existing line, the only reason I am using update is because I was told that was the right way of doing it?

Comment: If ID is auto number then SQL statement will be INSERT INTO ncmr (ncmrsr,ncmrsc) values ('$ncmrsr','$ncmrsc')

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6329/discussion-between-matt-ridge-and-avd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form method is `POST` so you need to add `hidden` field to embed/save the `ID` (value from $_GET) so when you submit this form you will get value from `textarea` as well as correct ID value using `$_POST['id']`.

I've removed some unrelated statement.

```
.....
.....
<?php

  $id=0;
  if(isset($_GET['id']))
     $id=$_GET['id'];

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $id=$_POST["id"];
        $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

        $ncmrsr = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ncmrsr']));
        $ncmrsc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['ncmrsc']));

        $query = "UPDATE ncmr SET ncmrsr = '$ncmrsr', ncmrsc = '$ncmrsc' WHERE id = $id";
        $result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
        if($result)
            echo '<p>Your comments have been successfully entered. Please <a href="list.php">return to the admin page</a> to view the final report!</p>';
            mysqli_close($dbc);
   }
   else
   {    
     if(!isset($_GET['id']))
       {
         header("Location: list.php");
         exit();
       }


      $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
      $query = "SELECT * FROM ncmr WHERE id = $id";

      $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

     if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {
         // The user row was found so display the user data
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
            echo'<div id="title"><h3 id="NCMR2">Non-Conforming Materials Report (NCMR:&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $row['rma'] . ')</h3></div>';
            echo "<form action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."' method='post'>";
            echo '<fieldset>';

            echo '<div id="box6">';
            // We know both $ncmrsr AND $ncmrsc are blank
            if (empty($row['ncmrsr']) && empty($row['ncmrsc'])) {
            // add comment.
                echo '<div id="ncmrsr"><span class="b">NCMR Supplier Response:<br /></span><textarea name="ncmrsr" rows="6" cols="105" ></textarea></div>';
                echo '<div id="ncmrsc"><span class="b">NCMR Supplier Comment:<br /></span><textarea name="ncmrsc" rows="6" cols="105" ></textarea></div>'; 

                echo '<div id="button2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Comment" /></div>';
                //Save ID so it can be used with POST request.
                echo "<input type='hidden' value='$id' name='id'/>"; 
                }
else {
            // echo the two fields.
            if (empty($row['ncmrsr'])) $row['ncmrsr'] ="Empty";
            if (empty($row['ncmrsc'])) $row['ncmrsc'] ="Empty";
                echo '<div id="ncmrsr"><span class="b">NCMR Supplier Response:</span><br />' . $row['ncmrsr'] . '</div>';
                echo '<div id="ncmrsc"><span class="b">NCMR Supplier Comment:</span><br />' . $row['ncmrsc'] . '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</fieldset>';
echo '</form>';
}

   }
  // End of check for a single row of user results
    else {
    echo '<p class="error">Please contact the web administrator, there seems to be an error!</p>';
  }

  mysqli_close($dbc);
  }
echo '</div>';

?>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: @MattRidge - My mistake here. please change - echo "<input type='hidden' value='$id' name='id'/>"; I've update it.

Comment: It displays the form, then when I type in test in both, and press Add Comment, I get just the logo, and nothing else.  It doesn't say thanks for entering data, etc...

Comment: yes I did, thank you very much, that posts.  You can't imagine how good it feels to actually get this thing working? It always seems no matter how much I know, there is that one thing that keeps me from getting a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cleanse any and all input from the user.  If $GET or $POST exist on the same line as a query string, you need to escape it like this one:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ncmr WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'";
```

Better yet, you're already using mysqli, so use a prepared statement instead.

If you're using mysqli, you may be using InnoDB, and it maybe that transactions are implicitly on, and auto-commit for the connection is off, so you may not be committing the transaction, at least if one is in effect.  Try adding mysqli_commit() before the close, and see if it helps.

In general, in development mode, you might wanna check your php.ini for error reporting, and check error_log on your web server to see if errors are reported there.  If the query fails, it may not show up on the page output, but it may show up in the error log.

Comment: if I add the $query the way you state, how would I then go along and "update" the post?

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you test if **mysqli_query($dbc, $query)** was successful

```
if (mysqli_query($dbc, $query)) {
    echo '<p>Your comments have been successfully entered. Please <a href="list.php">return to the admin page</a> to view the final report!</p>';
} else {
    echo mysqli_error($dbc);
}
```

Comment: updated the post as requested, and no errors come back at all, it says the comments have been successfully entered, etc... no errors under or or before it...

Comment: if you already have the **id** I'll suggest you **DON'T** pass it via $_GET but rather through a hidden input field. eg: 
**<input type="hidden" name="id" value="1">**

then access it through the php as $id = $_POST['id']. I bet this will work.

Comment: @cirisrob, the problem is that this is on a database where there are going to be dozens of lines of input, this will only work for one, not all of them...

Comment: I think AVD just did that. :-)

Comment: @cirisrob, yes he did, but I'll tell you though chat, and everything else, it was a long time coming, thanks for the help though. It's appreciated.